# SQL - mantain sort order for paginating data when change in real time

Tags: sql, pagination, real-time

I'm implementing a php page that display data in pagination format. My problem is that these data change in real time, so when user request next page, I submit last id and query is executed for retrieve more 10 rows from last id order by a column that value change in real time. For example I have 20 rows:

```
Id 1    col_real_time 5
Id 2    col_real_time 3 
Id 3    col_real_time 11
```

Etc

I get data sorted by `col_real_time` in ascending order, so result is

```
id 2, id 1, id 3
```

Now in realtime id 2 change in `col_real_time` 29 before user send request for next page, user now  send request for next results and because id 2 now is 29 he already see it.

How can I do?

Now in realtime id 2 change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have to take a snapshot of the data if you don't want the data to appear to change to the user. This isn't something that you can do very efficiently in SQL, so I'd recommend downloading the entire result set into a PHP session variable that can be persisted across pages. That way, you can just get rows on demand. There are Javascript widgets that will effectively do the same thing, but will send the entire result set to the client which is a bad idea if you have a lot of data.

This is not as easy to do as pure SQL pagination, as you will have to take responsibility for cleaning the stored var out when it's no longer needed. Otherwise, you'll rather quickly run out of memory.

Comment: I want retrive only first 30 real time data rows, then others row I can show in normal sort ( on column id that no change). For this purpose you think that temporary table is good solution? I can store 30 real time result in temporary table and then read others rows normaly without considering id saved in temporary table for avoid duplicate

Comment: As I said, doing this with pure SQL is not going to be efficient. Aside from the obvious slowness in creating a database object every time a user hits a page, most SQL databases are optimized for reads over writes. Furthermore, no database that I'm aware of can optimize or cache queries that create objects which means your queries would always run at their worst possible speed. You'd be much better off saving the data to a PHP variable.

Comment: I think that it possible paginating real time saving timestamp of request first time I load new data, then next page request I can send in post data the  original timestamp that was saved, so I get in SQL rows that are not create recent ( current time > original timestamp ) and considering also rows deleted after orginal timestamp. So, I get all history rows. Do you think that it work in this mode?

Answer (score 2):

If you have just a few pages, you could:

1. Save it to session and page over it, instead of going back to the
   database server.
2. Save it to a JSON object list and use Jquery to read it and page
   over it.
3. Save it to a temp table indicating generation timestamp, user_id and
   session_id, and page over it.